# How to verify the username in the url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, react-router

I can just type any username in the `url` and the same component gets rendered with the logged-in user's posts. Like when I'm logged in as rick, I can see my feed as `http://localhost:3000/profile/Rick/posts`
but if I type the `url` with any string or number or anything, it still renders the component. Like `http://localhost:3000/profile/xcxcxcxcx/posts`, it still shows the same posts as Rick's feed.

I think I have to verify the username.

Here's my code.

`UserProfile`

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { getCurrentUser } from "../actions/userActions"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

class UserProfile extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken")
    this.props.dispatch(getCurrentUser(authToken))
  }

  render() {
    const { isIdentifyingToken, username, email } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        {isIdentifyingToken ? null : (
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-content">
              <div className="media">
                <div className="media-left">
                  <figure className="image is-48x48">
                    <img
                      src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png"
                      alt="Placeholder image"
                    />
                  </figure>
                </div>
                <div className="media-content">
                  <p className="title is-4">{username}</p>
                  <p className="subtitle is-6">{email}</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <Link to={`/profile/${username}/posts`}>My Posts</Link>
              <br></br>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isIdentifyingToken: state.auth.isIdentifyingToken,
    username: state.auth.user.username,
    email: state.auth.user.email,
    id: state.auth.user._id
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserProfile)
```

`UserFeed`

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { getUserPosts, getCurrentUser } from "../actions/userActions"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import Cards from "./Cards"

class UserFeed extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const authToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken")
    if (authToken) {
      this.props.dispatch(getCurrentUser(authToken))
      if (this.props && this.props.userId) {
        this.props.dispatch(getUserPosts(this.props.userId))
      } else {
        return null
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { isFetchingUserPosts, userPosts } = this.props
    return isFetchingUserPosts ? (
      <p>Fetching....</p>
    ) : (
      <div>
        {userPosts &&
          userPosts.map((post) => {
            return <Cards key={post._id} post={post} />
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToPros = (state) => {
  return {
    isFetchingUserPosts: state.userPosts.isFetchingUserPosts,
    userPosts: state.userPosts.userPosts,
    userId: state.auth.user._id,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToPros)(UserFeed)
```

`Cards`

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { compose } from "redux"
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom"

class Cards extends Component {

  render() {
    const {title, description } = this.props.post
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-content">
          <div className="media">
            <div className="media-left">
              <figure className="image is-48x48">
                <img
                  src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png"
                  alt="Placeholder image"
                />
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div className="media-content" style={{ border: "1px grey" }}>
              <p className="title is-5">{title}</p>
              <p className="content">{description}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return state
}

export default compose(withRouter, connect(mapStateToProps))(Cards)
```

---

I have a backend route which verifies the user like: (it just takes the decoded object out from the token which contains the `userId` and verifies the user)

```js
    identifyUser: async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const userId = req.user.userId
            const user = await User.findOne({ _id: userId })
                if (!user) {
                    return res.status(500).json( {error: "No user found "})
                }
                return res.status(200).json( { user })
            } catch(error) {
                return next(error)
            }
        }
```

I'm not sure how do I verify the username in the params:(

**Edit**: `App.js`

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
              <Route path="/register" component={RegistrationForm} />
              <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/feed" component={Feed} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/post/new" component={NewForm} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/post/edit/:id" component={EditForm} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile/:username" component={UserProfile} />
              <PrivateRoute path="/profile/:username/posts" component={UserFeed} />
              <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that processes the URL? `Router` and `Route`s? `path="/profile/:username/posts"`

Comment: I've added the `App.js` at the end of my question, just now. @DrewReese. It's the `UserFeed` that processes the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserFeed` is rendered with the `component` prop, so it receives the [route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props), `match`, `location`, and `history`. The [`match`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match) prop is the one you should be interested in.

```
this.props.match.params.username
```

`UserFeed`, however, needs to react to the match prop updating and refetch the posts. Here I believe I'm correctly assuming the path's `username` is the same as the user's `userId` property. (*feel free to correct me if assumption is incorrect*). This you'll need the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  const { match: { params: { username } } } = this.props;
  const { match: { params: { username: prevUsername } } } = prevProps;
  if (prevUsername !== username) {
    // whatever other logic you need to validate user first
    this.props.dispatch(getUserPosts(username));
  }
}
```